# How to convert a Pyparsing Tree into a Data Flow Graph?

Tags: python, pyparsing, dataflow

I developed a python-like DSL compiler using pyparsing which generates an abstract syntax tree (AST). Form this AST, I want to create a data flow graph in networkx library. I just can't figure out how to transform the sequence (for), selection (if) and parallel constructs into data flow.

```
for x in range(1, 10):
    print(x)
```

The code above generates the following parse tree.

> [['STMT', 1, ['FOR', ['x', ['FUNCCALL', ['range', [[['NUMEXPR', ['MULTEXPR', '1']]],
> [['NUMEXPR', ['MULTEXPR', '10']]]]]], ['MULTISTMT', [1, 5], [[['STMT', 2, ['FUNCCALL', ['print',
> [[['NUMEXPR', ['MULTEXPR', 'x']]]]]]]]]]]]]]

Comment: Can you post some example code of what you have so far? Maybe a sample statement, and what the AST looks like?

Comment: @PaulMcG I have edited with question with an example parse tree.